# Count occurrences in multiple rows

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with a table containing data such as:

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
Banana
Orange
```

etc. I thought I could find my solution by doing something with a Pivot Table, but I have no idea how. I'm basically trying to count the number of occurrences for each value without having to change the function for every single text I want to count the occurrences of.

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to do? provide the required output

Comment: Are you trying to do "Apple   1    Banana    2     Orange    2"?

Comment: Sounds like a Pivot Table is the way to go. You can use the wizard and play around until you get something that looks like what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So setting up the pivot table like this did not work?:

Highlight the data

Go to INSERT ==> Pivot Table

[image]

I put it in C1 but you can choose where you want it.

I named the column Fruits and as you can see in the picture below it has that column name.  Add the column to both the rows and the value section.  If need be change the value to do the count.

[image]

note I would have put this in the comments but it required a picture.

Comment: How did you get "Counts of fruit" to show up? I can get "Row Labels" but no idea how to get counts of fruit.

Comment: @LewlSauce Drag the column to the values box.  If it does not automatically do a count then, click on it in the values section and choose "Value Field Settings".  Change to count.